# Why is my Classic Asp site running slow?

Tags: azure, asp-classic

I had one application which was developed in classic asp.

Now we deployed it in azure web site.

It is very slow .

Any ideas what can be reason for it

Comment: *"You had one"*... does it not exist any more?

Comment: How did you set up classic asp on azure (with a startup task, right?)
Does your website have a back-end? If so, did you migrate it too to Azure?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would look at is the database. 90% of the time when I see noticeably slow websites it is due to a database issue. Check to make sure all large tables are indexed, that can slow things down a ton. If you need more info on indexing, this thread does a pretty good job of explaining it: [How does database indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

Beyond that, it is very difficult to say what could be slowing your application down without more data on your application. Take note of when it is slow. Is it during certain processes or initial page loading or only on specific views? It's hard for me to even make suggestions without knowing the application.

If you can, install the app in a dev environment and comment out or change functions you suspect of being slow and observe the results. There are services like New Relic that can be very helpful in identifying bottlenecks and other issues but the good ones are all paid services and some are a bit pricey depending on your budget.

Hope this helps at least get you started in identifying your problems.

Comment: Web site is faster in normal server it happened after transferring to azure

Comment: New Relic won't help you with a Classic ASP site it is for .Net based web applications.

Answer (score 1):

I moved a Classic ASP site to Azure as well.  Azure is far less forgiving.

Make sure you add this directive to the top of EVERY page in your site:

```
<%@ language="vbscript" %>
```

Or to whatever scripting language you're using.  (It's an optional statement for non-Azure servers).  It should help speed up the site.

Particularly if using non-Latin characters, you may want to use this instead:

```
<%@ language="vbscript" codepage="65001" %>
```

(i.e. UTF-8)

Check for coding errors, such as in variable names, as well.  Azure will slow down noticeably.

A side note on running Classic ASP on Azure: Be careful of adding extensions.  Right now I'm having a huge problem with Dynatrace crashing my site but cannot completely uninstall it.  Also watch for large variability in your backendDuration.